# Op-amp saturation problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, saturation

**My design:** Two cascade connected inverting amplifiers.

**My problem:** The output of second amplifier is saturated from -0.6 to -0.7V. The supply of OPAMPs is dual (+5-5V).

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Note 1: Input is a 2V sinusoidal wave. 
Note 2: Output of second OPAMP is connected Analog Multiplexer (ADG708).

[image: Saturation]

Comment: What will happen if you disconnect the output from the multiplexer?

Answer (score 11):

The ADG708 can only handle negative inputs if it's in the -2.5 to 2.5V dual supply configuration. If you've got it hooked up to 0 and 5V, then that makes complete sense. There will be protection diodes in the ADG708 that will clamp to -0.7 or so below it's lower rail (VSS).

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit as shown should work correctly.  My best guess is that whatever the 2nd op-amp is feeding can't handle a negative input voltage.

Quick test is to simply disconnect the load from the output of the 2nd op-amp.  If the clipping goes away, you have found the problem.